# mysql trigger - is there anything like FOR EACH TABLE

Tags: mysql, triggers

MySql trigger is very interesting, but very tricky.

I have some problem, I want to run a trigger once `after insert on` .
I want to run my trigger once after rows inserted, is there anything like for each table``???

how to make this trigger run only once, but not for each row created.

```
CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `mydb`.`leave_taken_trigger`
AFTER INSERT ON `mydb`.`leave`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    set @lt:= (SELECT count(*) FROM `leave` where  (staff_leave_application_staff_id_staff = new.staff_leave_application_staff_id_staff and leave_type_id_leave_type = new.leave_type_id_leave_type) and active = 1 );

        INSERT INTO `leave_taken`(leave_type_id_leave_type, staff_id_staff, taken_days, updated) 
        VALUES (new.leave_type_id_leave_type, new.staff_leave_application_staff_id_staff, IFNULL(@lt,0), CURDATE())
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE taken_days=IFNULL(@lt,0), updated = CURDATE(); 

END$$
```

Comment: As far as I know, MySQL does not support statement level triggers (like e.g. PostgreSQL, Oracle or SQL Server)

Comment: I think that is not possible with trigger.

Comment: ok, please suggest other solutions

Comment: call the two statements of trigger either in your stored procedure or program after your insert statements.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want to update a table called 'leave_taken` when rows inserted to table `leave`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't achieve your requirement with trigger.
Your trigger will run in every row created.
I suggest you to using stored procedure from your code after the INSERT has successfully completed.